# if the digits in the odd position of the first number are in the even position in the second number

Tags: c++, loops

> Write a program that will read two natural numbers. The program should check if the digits in the odd position of the first number are in the even position in the second number.
>
> If this condition is met, the program prints DA, otherwise NE.
>
> The first digit is in the `0`<sup>th</sup> position, starting from the left.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number1, number2;
    cin >> number1 >> number2;

    int firstnumbercounter = 0;
    bool istrue = false;

    while (number1 > 0) {
        int temp = number2;
        while (temp > 0) {
            if (firstnumbercounter % 2 == 0) {
                int number1_digit = number1 % 10;
                int number2_digit = temp % 10;

                if (number1_digit == number2_digit) {
                    istrue = true;
                    break; 
                }
            }
            temp /= 10;
        }

        number1 /= 10;
        firstnumbercounter++;
    }

    if (istrue) {
        cout << "DA" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "NE" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting DA for everything.

The two for loops for iterating through the numbers and checking if the digits are the same, `firstnumbercounter` checks if the number is in an even or odd position.

Comment: This program checks that `number2` contains at least one digit that matches a digit in an even position in `number1`. It doesn't consider the digit's position in `number2`, and it stops as soon as it finds one matching digit. Also, it considers the rightmost (least significant) digit to be in position 0, not the leftmost (most significant) as the problem appears to require.

Comment: Make them `std::string number1, number2;` and get rid of one loop.

Comment: You wont get DA everytime. For example, entering 234 and 563 will result in NE.
Checking for even/odd position in number1 is missing.
And you are counting digits from the right, not from the left.

Comment: how do i do that please help

Comment: i tried making them arrays and comparing the elements but the test cases are made so that option is useless

Comment: *how do i do that please help* - Nope. This is YOUR assignment, not ours. If we do it for you, you don't learn anything. People have explained why you're having the problems that you're having, so you now know what you need to work on to fix them.

Comment: Read [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I tried your code and got `NE`. That's the risk you take when you let others decide what input to provide. You should force the issue with something like `int number1 = 1111, number2 = 2211; // Simulated user input` and skip reading from `cin`.

Comment: FWIW: The first test case I tried was `1` and `2`, as that was the simplest case I could think of where the numbers are different.

Comment: Idea: Run us through an example. Pick a case that should output "NE" and describe the steps your code should take to produce that output. [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is sometimes very effective. *Bonus: Determine where your code's actual execution differs from your expectation.*

Comment: I would either process the numbers as strings or else something like this: (1) multiply the shorter number by 10; (2) divide both by 10 if necessary to get an odd number of digits; (3) compare both numbers modulo 10; (4) divide by 100 and repeat (3) until an inequality is obtained or either number becomes zero.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just a gentle reminder that it might not be a good idea to `using namespace std;` for the [reasons listed here in this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) Also, for these types of problems in the future, you can try using a debugger, perusing other questions like [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Now, your entire `while` loop appears to have errors in how it runs.

```
 while (number1 > 0) {
        int temp = number2;
        while (temp > 0) {
            if (firstnumbercounter % 2 == 0) {
                int number1_digit = number1 % 10;
                int number2_digit = temp % 10;

                if (number1_digit == number2_digit) {
                    istrue = true;
                    break; 
                }
            }
            temp /= 10;
        }

        number1 /= 10;
        firstnumbercounter++;
    }
```

Let's break down this process:

1: First you check if the first number is greater than 0 - correct

2: You copy the second number to make sure the original value is kept - correct

3: You loop through the second number - mistake:

- You first check if the `firstnumbercounter` is even. Pretend this is the first loop and `firstnumbercounter` is 0. Then, you pass the condition of the `if` statement, and repeated check each digit of the second number, *without* actually knowing if this is the corresponding even index or if it even is in an even position.

Also, inside your if statement, you appear to stop the loop after anything matches, without making sure that it's the right parity for the index and other problems.

4: You go to the next digit of the first number - mistake but it's avoided:

- You only jump 1 digit, so you switch parity, from odd to even or from even to odd. You only want the odd digits of the first number. However, it's okay because when you loop through the copy of the second number, you make sure it's an odd digit. So, this can be simplified, but so far it's not going to cause a problem.

So overall, there are a few problems in your loops that could make your results incorrect.

A recommendation on my part is a new approach to this problem, which is to extract all the necessary digits from each number, and then compare these digits with each other so you can avoid the hassle of checking digit index parity in the middle of your loops.

The basic frame of this new approach:

1. Input
2. Extract odd digits from first number
3. Extract even digits from second number
4. Compare, and give answer

For example, since the problem defines the 0th digit to be the first one from the left, then we can still work our way backwards. If the number has an odd number of total digits, then the last digit must be an even. The opposite occurs when the total number of digits is even.

So, for the first number, where we need to extract odd digits

```
if (to_string(number1).size() % 2 == 1) { number1 /= 10; }
//the if statement tests if the first number has an odd number of total digits, which means the last digit is an "even." If so, then we remove it.
//I'm going to use a deque as the container for the digits
deque <int> number1OddDigits;
while (number > 0) {
    number1OddDigits.push_front(number % 10);
//since we are going from the back, we need to push it back into the front
    number /= 100;
//since we want to keep the ending digit odd, we go down by 2s
}
```

In the same way, we can adapt this to the second number, and then finally, just check all the digits in order, since they have already been extracted into the deques. Since this is your assignment, I'm going to leave you to it, but this answer is here to give you a sense of what's wrong, and what you could do instead.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of logical flaws in you code.

I will talk about the major ones only.

**First**

Your program is extracting digits from `number1` and `number2` from right side of number. If a number is having even number of digits, the extracted digits which your program consider as *odd* position will  actually *even* position digit and *even* position digit will actually  *odd* position.

Assume the two number are - `1234` and `4321`.
Your program extracting digits from number using `%` operator, the first digit it will extract from first number is `1234 % 10 = 4` and will consider it as a digit at *odd* position but, actually, it's a digit at *even* position and same goes for the second number as well.

For better understanding -

```
First number : 1234

           O    E    O    E     [O: odd position, E: even position]
           1    2    3    4
           |    |    |    |
         digit1 |    |    |
              digit2 |    |
                   digit3 |
                        digit4


      i.e. the digits at odd position in 1234 number are : 1 and 3

Second number : 4321

           O    E    O    E     [O: odd position, E: even position]
           4    3    2    1
           |    |    |    |
         digit1 |    |    |
              digit2 |    |
                   digit3 |
                        digit4


      i.e. the digits at even position in 4321 number are : 1 and 3
```

**Second**

If your program finds a digit at *odd* place in `number1` same as a digit at *even* place in `number2`, it will output `DA` irrespective of other digits at *odd* place in `number1` found or not.

and there are few more like unnecessary iterations etc. ...

Before writing a program, first try to come up with an algorithm/steps to solve the problem. **A suggestion** - *before reading below, take a pen and a paper and try to come with steps required to solve this problem.*

Algorithm (basic):

- [STEP:1] For each digit (starting from L.H.S.) at *odd* place in `number1`

  - Extract this digit (say `od`)
  - [STEP:2] For each digit (starting from L.H.S.) at *even* places in `number2`

    - Extract this digit (say `ed`)
    - Compare `od` with `ed`
    - If `od == ed`, go to [STEP:1]
    - If `od != ed`, go to [STEP:2]
  - If none of `ed` equal to `od`, print "NE" and exit
- If all digits at *odd* places in `number1` found at *even* places in `number2`, print "DA" and exit

From above steps, it's fairly clear that you need a mechanism to extract a digit from a number at a given position (where position may be *even* or *odd*).
Think about, how can you do it? *[take a pen and a paper, take some arbitrary number and try to write the steps with which you can extract digit at position `1`, `2` and so on]*.

Let's assume number is `1234`, to extract digit at position `2`:

```
1234 / 100 = 12
12 % 10 = 2
```

to extract digit at position `3`:

```
1234 / 10 = 123
123 % 10 = 3
```

to extract digit at position `1`:

```
1234 / 1000 = 1
1 % 10 = 1
```

The divisor (`100`, `1000` etc.) is varying based on position of digit to be extract in the given number.

If you look closely, the number of `0`<sup>s</sup> in divisor is based on position of digit to be extract. If we have total number of digits in given number then we can calculate the divisor, like this -

```
Number of zeros in divisor = total number of digit in number - position of digit to extract

e.g. 1234, extract second digit
     total number of digit in 1234 = 4
     No. of zeros in divisor = 4 - 2 = 2 i.e. 100 will be the divisor

     1234 / 100 = 12
     12 % 10 = 2
```

See some pattern here, lets write a function for it:

```
// paramter x : Given number
// parameter pos : Position of digit to extract from number x
// parameter nd : Total number of digits in number x
int getDigitAtPos (int x, int pos, int nd) {
    int d = 0;
    int divisor = 1;

    if (pos > nd) return -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < (nd - pos); ++i) {
        divisor = divisor * 10;
    }

    d = x / divisor;  
    return d % 10;
}
```

Similarly, you should write the other functions also, to perform a specific operation/task.

Now we will use this function to extract the digits at *even* and *odd* place from both the input number and perform the check.

```
#include <iostream>

// Function to calculate number of digits in a number
//
// paramter x : Given number
//
// Return : Total number of digits in number x
int getNumOfDigits (int x) {
    int n = 0;

    do {
        x = x / 10;
        n++;
    } while (x);

    return n;
}

// Function to extract a digit at a given position from a number
// 
// paramter x : Given number
// parameter pos : Position of digit to extract from number x
// parameter nd : Total number of digits in number x
//
// Return : Digit at a given position
int getDigitAtPos (int x, int pos, int nd) {
    int d = 0;
    int divisor = 1;

    if (pos > nd) return -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < (nd - pos); ++i) {
        divisor = divisor * 10;
    }

    d = x / divisor;

    return d % 10;
}

int main () {
    int num1;
    int num2;

    std::cout << "Enter two numbers: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> num1;
    std::cin >> num2;

    int dNum1 = getNumOfDigits(num1);
    int dNum2 = getNumOfDigits(num2);

    bool foundAll = true;  // go ahead with positive assumption

    // To extract odd place digits, i initialized with 1 
    // and incremented with 2 in every iteration - 1, 3, 5 and so on
    for (int i = 1; (i <= dNum1) && (foundAll); i = i + 2) {
        int od = getDigitAtPos (num1, i, dNum1);

        bool found = false;
        // To extract even place digits, j initialized with 2 
        // and incremented with 2 in every iteration - 2, 4, 6 and so on
        for (int j = 2; j <= dNum2; j = j + 2) {
            int ed = getDigitAtPos (num2, j, dNum2);
            if (ed == od) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            foundAll = false;
        }
    }

    std::cout << (foundAll ? "DA" : "NE") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out 
Enter two numbers: 
1234
4321
DA

# ./a.out 
Enter two numbers: 
1
21
DA

# ./a.out 
Enter two numbers: 
1111
21
DA

# ./a.out 
Enter two numbers: 
4567
23
NE
```

**NOTE:** This program can be implemented very efficiently using `string` and/or `STL`. I have shown you how to think and implement solution in steps. Kept the things as simple as possible for you, so that you comprehend easily. I am leaving it up to you to learn and improvise the implementation.